# OpenCV on Embedded Platform

Tags: c++, c, embedded, opencv

Can some suggest a test/development embedded platform to use with OpenCV.
I would like to develop an embedded video analytics solution, but I don't know where to start.
Some suggestion/ideas/hw starter kits?

Maybe some Pc-104 solutions with Intel Atom? Has someone made some test about performances on this platform or any other embedded platform?

Thanks

Comment: If you just want to play with OpenCV in Windows, then Visual Studio is pretty good and easy to get started with.

Answer (score 2):

A Pentium/PC built OpenCV application will run on any Atom platform with the same OS unmodified. This is because Atoms natively run Pentium executables.

If you are looking for a more embedded solution, there are OpenCV ports for the [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/).  SInce OpenCV is portable code, it can be compiled to most systems that provide a C/C++ compiler. I have successfully used OpenCV on ARM, MIPS and XScale processors.

As for mobile platforms, there are ports to the iPhone, Android and various Windows CE/Mobile/Embdeed versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a **very** small option, I strongly recommend the Gumstix Overo series.  I use them for my Computer Vision research, and they work really well.  There are a couple of options for processors, I'd recommend the Overo Tide module, which has 512 MB of RAM, and an onboard DSP for offloading some CV operations.  Combine this with a Tobi expansion board and a few cables, and you've got a full embedded computer vision research platform for ~$350.  They also sell a small camera, which I'm still getting around to trying out.  What's nice about the Gumstix is you can just build OpenCV onboard, which saves you some of the headaches with BitBake type solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally recommend TI OMAP platforms - Beagleboard xM and PandaBoard.

Those boards have embedded video input, run Linux, and have more than enough performance to run OpenCV. They are also extremely portable and have good community support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean OpenCV the computer vision library originally developed by Intel? I would be inclined to start with Moblin, Intel's embedded Linux, at moblin.org and for hw use a netbook or any PC that Moblin supports. Hook up a supported webcam from the list at www.qbik.ch/usb/devices/search_res.php?pattern=webcam . 
There is a Wikipedia entry that might help. Your project sounds like fun!
cheers -- Rick

Comment: Yes, I mean OpenCV, the intel computer vision library.
My problem is not about the operating system, but the hardware where to compile my code.
I was thinking about some PC-104 solutions or something else.

Comment: Now that development of OpenCV has been handed off to Willow Garage, I would instead recommend using Ubuntu, which is WG's development environment of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Blackfin kit from Analog Devices. Analog Devices have created a [library](http://www.analog.com/en/embedded-processing-dsp/blackfin/BF_IPTBX_00/processors/product.html) similar to opencv for the blackfin DSP processor.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Symbian Simulator for this they Nokia have there Open CV for Symbian for hardware testing you have to drop the mail to them they will provide u the hardware through the telnet for given time of time

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV does not need any "special" hardware to function. You can use it fully using images from normal files (e.g. JPG)

Have you looked at some of the tutorials/code? Do they require something specific that you do not have?

Answer (score 0):

[Vision Components](http://www.vision-components.com/en/) seem to support the OpenCV in their Smart Cameras (see this [article](http://www.automation.com/content/opencv-now-running-on-all-vision-components-smart-cameras)).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am late to answer.

I have recently used opencv3.4.6 with PC-104 boards (PCM3365) for an INDUSTRIAL Application.

Only thing to note is that when i start webcamera using cv::Videocapture, it takes a long time to open (around 30-40secs), otherwise everything is fine.

Good Luck